# Finding an element using regex selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I have an element whose value changes dynamically. This is the following:

"Pay 13.61"

I want to save the element 13.61 in a string and compare with 0.

This is how the appium structure looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cQMV.png)

I want to extract the value of pay.
This is what I did:

```
String amt = wait.until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='Pay '+%s]"))).getText();
        logger.info(amt);
        logger.info("Cash Pay succeeded!");
```

Its not able to find the element, can anyone please help. Thanks. :)

Comment: Why can't you simply use `//*[starts-with(text(),'Pay ')]`?

Comment: @supputuri didnt work :(