# Regex for a specific string followed by a number

Tags: regex

I have a specific string followed by number (which changes).
I want a regex function for that.

The string is `Pay $3.14`

The regex I am using is:

```
"^(Pay|[0-9]*)$"
```

But it is not giving me the result.

Can someone please guide?

Comment: `^(Pay\\s+\\d+\\.?\\d+)$`

Comment: `^(Pay\s+\$\d+(\.\d+)?)$`

Comment: What is your question? Do you wish to confirm the string contains a digit? Do you wish to extract each sequence of digits? Must the string begin with "Pay"? Must the string contain the representation of a dollar amount?

Comment: you can use this one, `^[^\$]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at another question of yours [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125938/finding-an-element-using-regex-selenium-java], and I think this is what you want:

https://regex101.com/r/OI9Tcq/1

If `$` is not included in the text, then you can use:
https://regex101.com/r/B8i4xe/1

Both expressions will grab just the numbers, as per this:

> "Pay 13.61" I want to save the element 13.61 in a string and compare with 0.

Original Answer

https://regex101.com/r/OI9Tcq/1

In the event that this was more in line with what you want, I've attached my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\bPay\s*\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3rMBgW/1). The number is in capturing group 1.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Pay                      'Pay'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```